# Replace File using Assets with S3 + Cloudfront

Tags: assets, s3, cloudfront

I'm attempting to replace an existing JPG image on S3 that's managed by Assets, but it appears the new file doesn't replace the existing one on S3.

My first thought was that it was an issue with browser caching, but I have it disabled, and, when viewing the file's URL in a different browser, I still see the old image, so, I'm confident the new file isn't ever making it to S3.

I do not see any errors in the EE control panel; everything else is working without any problems (upload, delete, move, etc.).

Steps to Reproduce:

- Upload a file to S3 in the EE CP using Assets
- Upload another file with the same name to to same folder
- Select "replace the existing file" at the prompt
- Right click the thumbnail/file, view file; file on S3 hasn't been updated.

This install is on EE 2.7.2 with Assets 2.2.2. Will not be able to provide credentials for troubleshooting, as it's behind a VPN on infrastructure I cannot modify; hopefully you can reproduce in your test environment.

Comment: Nick, I can't reproduce this locally at all, but I *am* using a slightly modified version of Assets - if you could get in touch with me via support@pixelandtonic.com, I could provide it to you for a test run to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been working like maniacs to hit a deadline on this project, and hadn't had time to deploy the updated version of Assets that P&T's support quickly provided; although I did notice yesterday that the file I was testing this issue with had updated... apparently it just took a few days.

I strongly suspect this was a problem for us because we're using Cloudfront to serve these files, not plain vanilla S3.

There are several [posts in the regular Stack Exchange site that address this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086240/how-can-i-update-files-on-amazons-cdn-cloudfront); in order for Assets to handle this automatically, it looks like a special API call would need to be performed. Don't know if that's possible or not, but, at least there's a theoretical solution.

Barring that feature support:

- advise content creators to upload files with a version number in the
  filename instead of replacing them directly
- wait a few days for the new version to propigate on its own
- issue a cloudfront update manually via an API call or the AWS control panel

Answer (score 2):

When updating files connected to a CloudFront distribution you can speed up the required waiting period by invalidating the modified files. In many cases this reduces the waiting period to update CloudFront edge locations from days to under an hour.

Details here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html